# Why do I get a segmentation fault (core dumped) when I comment the malloc() call?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc

```
int main()
{
    struct stuff
    {
        int num;
    }*foo;

    // If I comment the line below, I get core dump error.
    // Why?
    foo = (struct stuff *)malloc(sizeof(struct stuff));
    (*foo).num = 7;

    printf("%d\n", (*foo).num);
}
```

Comment: `foo` is pointer it needs to point to memory.

Comment: If you use an uninitialized pointer, you get whatever crash you deserve (if you're lucky; if you're unlucky, it seems to work — until something changes).  Note that is is conventional to write `foo->num = 7;` rather than `(*foo).num = 7;` — all else apart, it is less typing, but more importantly, it is clearer, especially if there is more than one level of structure involved (`(*(*ptr).ptr_member).data = 7;` is harder to read and write than `ptr->ptr_member->data = 7;`).

Comment: You forgot to compile with all warnings and debug info, e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). Read also [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are only allowed to dereference a *valid* pointer.

In your case, `foo` being an automatic local variable, unless initialized explicitly, contains some indeterminate value, i.e, it points to an arbitrary memory location,  which is pretty much invalid from the point of your program.

In case, you do not assign a valid pointer to `foo` (returned by `malloc()`, for example), `foo` points to some *indeterminate* memory location and attempt to dereference it will invoke [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Segmentation fault is one of the side effects of UB.

Answer (score 0):

foo is a pointer, it must point to address
If you dont want to use malloc you can do follow it:

```
struct stuff _foo;
foo = &_foo;
(*foo).num = 7;
```

Answer (score 0):

`foo` in your example is an uninitialized pointer to a struct you just defined. If you doesn't initialize with a valid memory chunk it will always result in SEGFAULT. Another bad thing with your code is that even if you allocate memory for it, than you don't free it.

If you don't want to use `malloc` just make it local variable:

```
int main()
{
    struct stuff
    {
        int num;
    }foo;

    foo.num = 7;

    printf("%d\n", foo.num);
}
```